# Error: type org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker does not take parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have a OSGi project and I am using Maven. In a bundle I need to import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker, and create a property:

```
...
import org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker;
...

private ServiceTracker<Object, Object> serviceTracker;
```

I clearly have org.eclipse.osgi in my dependencies as denoted in below (part of my pom.xml).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0.v20120529-1548</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Within Eclipse, I can find the definition of the class.

```
public class ServiceTracker<S, T> implements 
             ServiceTrackerCustomizer<S, T> 
{
   ...
}
```

However, when I compile my project by maven command:

```
mvn clean install
```

I got the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project <my project name>: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR]  <link to my source code dir>/Activator.java:[75,27] type 
org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker does not take parameters
```

What the hell is happening?

Comment: Do you have any other dependencies in the pom or a parent pom? It looks to be picking up an older version of the ServiceTracker class from somewhere.

Comment: Or a dependency (not managed, but direct dependency) in the parent pom. Btw.: you should use org.osgi.core and org.osgi.compendium dependencies for compilation with "provided" scope instead of the artifact that implements the specification.

Comment: @NickWilson: At first, I also think like you so I tried to compile it separately - create a new standalone project, only declare the dependency and the property, and compile project. But the error is still there.

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos: This bundle is going to be deployed withing Karaf with equinox core. So it could have a lot of potential run-time errors when compiling the bundle with org.osgi.core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are compiling your code with Java 7. OSGi released class files compiled with the undocumented `-target jsr14` flag. Javac 7 refuses to recognize generic signatures from those class files. See http://blog.osgi.org/2012/10/43-companion-code-for-java-7.html.

Also, you should not compile against the Equinox implementation but instead against the OSGi companion code jars. You will want version 4.3.1 or later. See http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.osgi|osgi.core|4.3.1|jar.

Comment: Thank you. I downgraded my java back to 1.6_u45 and now it works like a charm.

Comment: Those tips and the link to the blogpost were really helpful!